# Error Date Format Import Excel to Mysql using PHPExcel Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

I want to import file Excel into Mysql using Library PHPExcel on Codeigniter, My code Successfully insert data to database, but date format only 0000-00-00 if I change type data format to integer, field date inserted number 31248.

this my controller function

```
public function upload_excel()
{
  $fileName = $this->input->post('file', TRUE);

  $config['upload_path'] = './assets/excel/'; 
  $config['file_name'] = $fileName;
  $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
  $config['encrypt_name']= TRUE;
  $config['max_size'] = 0;

  $this->load->library('Upload', $config);
  $this->upload->initialize($config); 

  if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
   $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
   $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan',$error); 
   redirect('sio'); 
 } else {
   $media = $this->upload->data();
   $inputFileName = './assets/excel/'.$media['file_name'];

   try {
    $inputFileType = IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
  } catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
  }

  $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
  $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
  $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
  for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){  
   $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
     NULL,
     TRUE,
     FALSE);
   $data = array(
     "kd_pekerja"=> trim(preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $rowData[0][1])), // opsional hapus spasi depan
                "no_ktp"=> $rowData[0][2],
                "nm_karyawan"=> $rowData[0][3],
                "tgl_lahir"=> $rowData[0][4],
                "no_sio"=> $rowData[0][5],
                "tgl_buat"=> $rowData[0][6],
                "ms_berlaku"=> $rowData[0][7],
                "ket"=> $rowData[0][8]);


   $this->db->insert("tbl_sio",$data);
 } 
   unlink($inputFileName); // hapus file temp
   $count = $highestRow;
   $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan','Upload berhasil, Total: <b>'.$count.'</b> data.'); 
   redirect('sio');

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use `PHPExcel_Shared_Date` class

```
 $worksheet=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
 foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(FALSE); // Loop all cells, even if it is not set
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
      if (PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell)) {
         $date=date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($cell->getValue()));
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: It's still fill with number.